# How to use the LaTeX dev formats in l3build regression testing?

Tags: l3build

I'm giving my first steps in packaging, and learning my way through `l3build`, which is great, and has spared of a lot of work in the task, but there's one thing I'm not being able to figure out: how to use the LaTeX dev formats for regression testing.

I had been aware of their existence since they were announced (https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2019-FMi-TUB-tb125mitt-dev-format.pdf), I believe it to be a very welcome release workflow improvement, and I'd like to use it, now that I have the opportunity to.

As far as I could grasp from `l3build`'s documentation we have `checkengines` (plural) and `checkformat` (singular) as variables to set, the latter defaults to `"latex"`. We can also specify non-standard engine/format combinations with `specialformats`. I haven't tried to "massage" `checkengines` with some `specialformats` since that seemed stretching the semantics of the variables names (I couldn't think of any obvious way to do it either). I also would not like to *replace* `"latex"` with `"latex-dev"` in `checkformat`, I'd like to run the regression tests in *both* of them (I'll gladly pay the time it takes for this purpose).

It seems to me that `l3build` would be one of the most prominent use cases of the LaTeX dev formats, so I presume there is some (easy) way to do this. But I can't seem to figure it out. How could I do it?

**Edit:** With the help of Ulrike in the comments, I was able to get some steps ahead with this, but not quite there yet.

With a `build.lua` such as:

```lua
#!/usr/bin/env texlua

-- Identify the bundle and module
bundle = ""
module = "mytest"

-- Two runs for label testing
checkruns = 2

-- Include LaTeX dev formats in regression testing
checkengines =
  {
    "pdftex" ,
    "xetex" ,
    "luatex" ,
    "pdftexdev" ,
    "luatexdev" ,
    "xetexdev"
  }
specialformats = specialformats or {}
specialformats["latex"] = specialformats["latex"] or
  {
    pdftexdev = { binary = "pdftex"   , format = "pdflatex-dev" },
    xetexdev  = { binary = "xetex"    , format = "xelatex-dev"  },
    luatexdev = { binary = "luahbtex" , format = "lualatex-dev" },
  }
```

I can get the checks running, in the sense that the correct binaries are called with the correct formats (as far as I can tell).

However, the result comparison step still goes amiss somehow. Consider the simple test file below `mytest01.lvt`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\input{regression-test}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:section-1}

\START

\setbox0=\hbox{\ref{sec:section-1}}
\showbox0

\OMIT

\end{document}
```

Its results are engine specific, and hence have to be compared to the engine's results, rather than to the default engine. So we save the results for each engine with:

```
$ l3build save -e pdftex mytest01
$ l3build save -e luatex mytest01
$ l3build save -e xetex mytest01
$ l3build save -e pdftexdev mytest01
$ l3build save -e luatexdev mytest01
$ l3build save -e xetexdev mytest01
```

But then the checks, which we have just saved, fail (for `luatexdev` in this case):

```
$ l3build check
Running checks on
  mytest01 (1/1)
          --> failed


  Check failed with difference files
  - ./build/test/mytest01.luatexdev.diff
```

Examination of the results show that `mytest01.luatexdev.tlg` is identical to `mytest01.luatex.tlg` (as I'd expect). And `mytest01.luatexdev.diff` is just like the diff between `mytest01.luatexdev.tlg` and the default `mytest01.tlg` (this is my guess at what is going on).

Comment: why don't you want to define a special format? That is what I would do.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What I meant is that adding "formats" to `checkengines` was stretching. But perhaps that's not what is required. And it is not that I "don't want", it is really that I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: For example, if I add an entry for `"pdftex"` in `specialformats`, I still have one `format` (singular) key to add it.

Comment: well I would try `specialformats = specialformats or {} specialformats["latex"] = specialformats["latex"] or   { pdftexdev    = {format = "pdflatex-dev"}}` and then use `pdftexdev` in checkengines. (untested, so typos possible).

Comment: Sorry @UlrikeFischer I don't understand the syntax and could not make it work... :(

Comment: you could look at the build lua in tagpdf or pdfresources.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I will! Thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I could finally make it work with the examples. The start there is just initializing the variable, got it. And I had to specify the binaries too, since otherwise they would be inferred from the engine name. Would you like to answer? (I can do a self answer too, if you prefer).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer May I add a question? Why does it have to be `luahbtex` as opposed to the plain `luatex`?

Comment: the standard latex engine is luahbtex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah! Try as I might, I'd not have figured that one out by myself... Thanks again!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I correct myself. I actually could not make this work. I could setup additional `checkengines` and set their respective `specialformats`, and the checks run all right. But, in tests which require the logs to be saved in engine specific fashion, it does not work. If I save the log with `l3build save -e luatexdev mycheck01` and immediately after make the check with `l3build check -e luatexdev mycheck01` the check fails. I think I'm giving up on this one, it all seems non-standard enough that I should probably not be doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to leave this one unanswered, I'll provide a self answer (thanks to @UlrikeFischer's comments).  It turns out Ulrike's hints were spot on (as usual), and the trouble I was finding with `lualatex-dev` was due to an upstream bug (reported and fixed at https://github.com/latex3/l3build/issues/215, thanks @MarcelKruger), and which is already part of the latest `l3build` release.  With that in hand we can go with the following setup.

`build.lua`:

```lua
-- Identify the bundle and module
bundle = ""
module = "mypackage"

-- Two runs for label testing
checkruns = 2

-- Set up tests for dev format
checkengines = {"pdftex","luatex","xetex","pdftexdev","luatexdev","xetexdev"}
specialformats = specialformats or {}
specialformats.latex =
  {
    pdftexdev = { binary = "pdflatex-dev" , format = "" } ,
    luatexdev = { binary = "lualatex-dev" , format = "" } ,
    xetexdev  = { binary = "xelatex-dev"  , format = "" } ,
  }
```

And the test file `mytest01.lvt`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\input{regression-test}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:section-1}

\START

\setbox0=\hbox{\ref{sec:section-1}}
\showbox0

\OMIT

\end{document}
```

We can save test results as:

```
$ l3build save -e pdftex mytest01
$ l3build save -e luatex mytest01
$ l3build save -e xetex mytest01
$ l3build save -e luatexdev mytest01
$ l3build save -e xetexdev mytest01
```

`pdftexdev` is not included in the save step, meaning it will be compared to the default engine, which is `pdftex`. Unfortunately, we cannot spare the save step for `luatexdev` and `xetexdev`, since the default is not configurable by engine, so we must save those.

An experimental observation for the `luatexdev` setup: for it, one can go with either `binary = "lualatex-dev" , format = ""` or `binary = "luahbtex" , format = "lualatex-dev"`. The seemingly more standard `binary = "luatex" , format = "lualatex-dev"` does grant me a nasty "WARNING: you are switching to fmtutil's per-user formats. Please read the following warnings!" etc.

Note that we could go with a slightly less wordy setup, not requiring to set `specialformats`, and just do, for example:

```lua
checkengines = {"pdftex", "luatex", "xetex", "pdflatex-dev"}
```

This works because `l3build-check.lua` does the following when running the tests:

```lua
local binary = engine
local format = gsub(engine,"tex$",checkformat)
-- Special binary/format combos
local special_check = specialformats[checkformat]
if special_check and next(special_check) then
  local engine_info = special_check[engine]
  if engine_info then
    binary    = engine_info.binary  or binary
    format    = engine_info.format  or format
    checkopts = engine_info.options or checkopts
  end
end
```

Hence, for the `"pdflatex-dev"` engine, the binary will be `pdflatex-dev`, and since it does not end with `tex$`, the `format` `gsub` regexp won't match, and the format will also be `pdflatex-dev`. I preferred to go with the wordier setup, because it appeared somewhat flimsy to rely on such an implementation detail to get it right. So, with `specialformats` we can explicitly set `binary` and `format` independently of that `gsub` regexp.